# MAXIMUS IV GENE-Z/GEN3 Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have ran out of ideas and I hope this is the correct place to ask. I upgraded my win 7 pro 64 to windows 10. I thought it was a good idea at the time but now my etherhet card does not work now. My motherboard is MAXIMUS IV GENE-Z/GEN3 and the network card on it is intel 82579v.

Let me elaborate on does not work. I think that windows 10 seems to think it has the right driver for it. In device manager there is not a single warning in the entire hardware list. I tried updating / removing / re installing drivers but no luck so far. I would greatly appreciate any help.

P.S. Where is the cmd on this freakin os so I can see if I can ping stuff. Holy crap why did I touch a perfectly functioning windows 7...